# MaterialComponents actionbar text cannot be made lowercase? (textAllCaps does not work)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, themes

I am using this theme `Theme.MaterialComponents`.

My problem is that I added some menu, which is simple clickable text, and that is displayed on the action bar as **UPPERCASE** (see the image below):

[image: a problem]

My resourse file contains this text as follows:

```
<string name="register_user_action_v2">Создать</string>
```

I tried adding **actionMenuTextAppearance** styles to my theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDarkMaterialDesignBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">

...

<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>

...

</style>
```

where `MyMenuTextAppearance`:

```
<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

But still, it does not work.

How to make this text looks like normal (e.g. **Создать**, not **СОЗДАТЬ** )

**P.S.** Maybe it is a problem with my `@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu` and I should use something different for `MaterialComponent` theme?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar in the layout with a theme overlay? Are you using setSupportActionBar(toolbar)?

Comment: No I dont use  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: if you know the solution for Toolbar with MaterialComponent theme I could add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ../>

toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //Material toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

with this style:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/actionbar_menu</item>
  </style>

  <style name="actionbar_menu" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
```

[image]